# Attempt to present GameViewController on ViewController which is waiting for a delayed presention of GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController to complete

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, game-center, modalviewcontroller

I get that error in the debug log every time I run my app.  I click Find Game, it takes me to main screen, the keyboard doesn't work due to this error and when I hit the back button, the view controller it just pops back up (again due to this error). I can't figure out how to fix it so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
// A peer-to-peer match has been found, the game should start
- (void)turnBasedMatchmakerViewController: (GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match
{

// Display default view  [presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

[presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    // Present next controller here
[presentingViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GamePlayScene" sender:match];
}];

// Removing line below fixes  Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <GameNavigationController: 0x78f4f820> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!

// [self dismissModalViewController];
```

Answer (score 0):

The GameKit documentation states that your didFindMatch method should dismiss the view controller and perform needed actions on the match object.

Your method should look like this.

```
- (void)turnBasedMatchmakerViewController: (GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match {
    // Dismiss the view controller
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    // Perform your logic
}
```

From [GameKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate/turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:didFindMatch:):

> Your game should dismiss the view controller and use the match object
>   to show the current state of the match to the player.

Comment: Still the same problem. 

   `// Dismiss the view controller
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    
   // Present next controller here
    [presentingViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GamePlayScene" sender:match];`

Comment: What is your `presentingViewController` ?

Comment: `@interface GameKitHelper: NSObject<GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate, GKLocalPlayerListener>
{
    UIViewController *presentingViewController;
}`
--- Break ---  `- (void)findMatchWithMinPlayers:(int)minPlayers
                     maxPlayers:(int)maxPlayers
viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    presentingViewController = viewController;"`
-Break
`//  This line of code breaks the back button on game screen
    [presentingViewController presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}`

None of my actual View Controllers are called presentingViewController.